# flexible table with tbody scrolling issues

Tags: css

I'm facing issue while I was make `<tbody>` scrollable. After I've made the `<tbody>` scrollable `<thead>`'s `<th>` & `<tbody>`'s `<td>`s got misaligned.

Can you help me on this

My `HTML`:

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" class="sortingtable scroll">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name <i></i>
            </th>
            <th>Web Address <i></i>
            </th>
            <th>Office Location <i></i>
            </th>
            <th>Configuration <i></i>
            </th>
            <th>Status <i></i>
            </th>
            <th>Queue <i></i>
            </th>
            <th><span class="actions">Action</span> 
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Tester A</td>
            <td>bat-1.sj</td>
            <td> California</td>
            <td>Normal config.</td>
            <td>Online</td>
            <td>5 Jobs</td>
            <td> <a href="#/connect" class="btn_connect">Connect</a>

            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Tester B</td>
            <td>bat-1.sj</td>
            <td> California</td>
            <td>Normal config.</td>
            <td>Online</td>
            <td>9 Jobs</td>
            <td> <a href="#/connect" class="btn_connect">Connect</a>

            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Tester C</td>
            <td>bat-1.sj</td>
            <td> California</td>
            <td>Normal config.</td>
            <td>Online</td>
            <td>2 Jobs</td>
            <td> <a href="#/connect" class="btn_connect">Connect</a>

            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Tester D</td>
            <td>bat-1.sj</td>
            <td> California</td>
            <td>Normal config.</td>
            <td>Online</td>
            <td>4 Jobs</td>
            <td> <a href="#/connect" class="btn_connect">Connect</a>

            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Tester E</td>
            <td>bat-1.sj</td>
            <td> California</td>
            <td>Normal config.</td>
            <td>Online</td>
            <td>7 Jobs</td>
            <td> <a href="#/connect" class="btn_connect">Connect</a>

            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Tester F</td>
            <td>bat-1.sj</td>
            <td> California</td>
            <td>Normal config.</td>
            <td>Online</td>
            <td>5 Jobs</td>
            <td> <a href="#/connect" class="btn_connect">Connect</a>

            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Tester G</td>
            <td>bat-1.sj</td>
            <td> California</td>
            <td>Normal config.</td>
            <td>Online</td>
            <td>11 Jobs</td>
            <td> <a href="#/connect" class="btn_connect">Connect</a>

            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Tester H</td>
            <td>bat-1.sj</td>
            <td> California</td>
            <td>Normal config.</td>
            <td>Online</td>
            <td>6 Jobs</td>
            <td> <a href="#/connect" class="btn_connect">Connect</a>

            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Tester I</td>
            <td>bat-1.sj</td>
            <td> California</td>
            <td>Normal config.</td>
            <td>Online</td>
            <td>3 Jobs</td>
            <td> <a href="#/connect" class="btn_connect">Connect</a>

            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

`CSS`:

```
table.scroll {
    width: 100%;
    /* Optional */
    /* border-collapse: collapse; */
    border-spacing: 0;
    border: 2px solid black;
}
table.scroll tbody, table.scroll thead {
    display: block;
}
thead tr th {
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    /*text-align: left;*/
}
table.scroll tbody {
    height: 100px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
tbody {
    border-top: 2px solid black;
}
tbody td, thead th {
    width:auto;
    /* Optional */
    border-right: 1px solid black;
}
tbody td:last-child, thead th:last-child {
    border-right: none;
}
```

Here's my [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/v7rvvqew/1)

Comment: Hi There, welcome to stackoverflow. Thank you for including some example code of your work. I recommend trying to use the **snippet** option within the text editor to show your code.

Comment: you cannot control the height of a table. thus you cannot apply overflow: hidden to it. you apply display: block so your browser accepts height, but you lose the regular table behaviour with this as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you want to `fix` your `<thead>` and make your `<tbody>` scroll.

For this I'll recommend [**floatThead**](http://mkoryak.github.io/floatThead), viz I've used also for making the same.

Here, I've created a [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/vivekkupadhyay/v7rvvqew/8), please have a look.

The main reason behind, misbehaving of your `<tbody>` elements is that you've declared:

```
table.scroll tbody, table.scroll thead {
    display: block;
}
```

> `<thead` is a table-cell and as per `CSS` its `display:table-cell` and
>   you've changed its behavior by altering its default property.

Comment: Yes it works with little error. I have added the FloatThread js file and called it. Now table header & body cell are aligned perfectly but Table Header is gone up while scroll action perform. It should be stick. I m using angularjs. I m not sure what i missed.
Thanks for your help :) I m looking forward to your reply

Comment: Can you create a **JSFiddle** as in mine there's no gone-up thing.

Comment: It works when i put js in the same html file, Previously i used to keep it on common js (separate js). So it wasn't work, Now it works

And is it possible to create a directive for this in angular?

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm newbie to Angular :)

Comment: Ok No probs. Thanks for your help